# Redirect website root to subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I redirect all requests going to web root to another folder (e.g. public/)?

I've already tried this (contents of .htaccess in web root):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1
```

But now I have duplicate content for addresses:
**address.tld/** and **address.tld/public/**

I would like to redirect **address.tld/public/** to **address.tld/**, so there won't be any duplicates, but I just don't know how to do it and not get into redirecting cycle...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these rules:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /public/
RewriteRule ^public/(.*) /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule !^public/ public%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

With mod_rewrite you'll not get redirecting cycles.

Comment: I got into a cycle using 'Redirect permanent' request, sorry for misinformation.